# Group data points by third variable and display the group name in legend

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to create a column chart with grouped column representing one division and data points with same division has the same column color.
Here is my jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/codelock/x5w32u69/16/

In this example the x axis is the location, the y axis is the production and I want to group them by another variable division. Locations with the same division will have same color. For example, foo1 and foo2 will have same division - division1 and therefore has same color red.
I could get the chart to display different colors, but they are not showed up in the legends. I want the divisions to be shown in the legends like-
`division1(red), division2(black), division3(blue)`

How do I add these legends with the existing situation?
I am open to revamp the code from scratch if the solution is possible.

Note: The key point to note here is that x axis for each division is different. So location is unique to it's division. therefore it is not this kind of chart: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide divisions into series and place points on a proper location by `x` value.

```
    series: [{
        name: "division1",
        color: 'red',
        data: [{
            y: 20,
            x: 0
        }, {
            y: 30,
            x: 1
        }]
    }, {
        name: "division2",
        color: 'black',
        data: [{
            y: 10,
            x: 2
        }, {
            y: 20,
            x: 3
        }, {
            y: 20,
            x: 4
        }]
    }, {
        name: "division3",
        color: 'blue',
        data: [{
            y: 20,
            x: 5
        }]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c7jnsdaw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data